# Generate testng-results.xml in selenium after automation completed

Tags: java, xml, selenium, testng

I am new to selenium. Using Java and Selenium web driver I had 140 test cases. I have executed. After successful execution unfortunately i have deleted the testng-results.xml file. Now how to retrieve the file? usually to run all the test case will take 8 hrs. but i have all 140 test cases individual xml and html files in separate folder inside test-output folder.

Please help me using these individual files of xml to generate testng-results.xml

Comment: Please explain what the actual issue is. If you have the individual reports for each test, then combine those to form the overall report.

Answer (score 0):

There is another report that gets generated called emailable-report.html which should have most of the details  required.

Comment: Yes its there. but i required testng-results.xml to generate error document and functional document.